# BuildRowsetFromXML question

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are trying to bring into our emails dynamic content from our websites; I am working on a way to achieve this. I imported a sample of the XMLs that we would generate of the website into a Data Extension and I am trying to reference these via amp script. I do not get an error message I just receive a blank screen.

I saved the xmls in a non sendable data extension. Code I wrote is below:

```
%%[

var @SubscriberKey 
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows('EE_BookingExtensions_Cris',0,'[Tour Number] desc','SubscriberKey',SubscriberKey) 
SET @rowcount = RowCount(@rows) 

if @rowcount > 0 then 
    for @i = 1 to @rowcount do 
        set @row = row(@rows,@i) 
        set @tour = field(@row,"Tour Number")
    ]%% 
    %%[next @i]%% 

    Tour Code from Sendable DE:%%=v(@tour)=%%<br>

%%[endif]%%

<br>

%%[

SET @xml = Lookuprows('XML_CRISSS','TourCode',@tour)

for @j = 1 to rowcount(@xml) do
    SET @xmlrows = row(@xml,@j)
    SET @xmlls = field(@xmlrows,"CODE__HTML")
    SET @brochure = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xmlls,'/TourInfo/SellingCompanies/SellingCompany/Brochure/Name',1)
    set @TourName = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xmlls,'/TourInfo/TourName',1)
]%%

%%[ next @j ]%%
<br>Your brochure is: %%=v(@brochure)=%%
<br>Your Tour Name is: %%=v(@TourName)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's set somewhere else, but I don't see where you've assigned a value to `@subscriberKey`.  It's also not referenced in your initial lookup properly -- the variable is missing the `@` prefix.

Don't you want to nest your loops?

Can there be multiple `XML_CRISSS` records for a single Tour and multiple `SellingCompanies` per Tour?

Assuming that's the case, I've updated your code to match the format of [**my go-to XML parsing method**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/cc72b3662c43ba2c1650cccc979ee137).

It's better to check to make sure your XML nodes exist before trying to pull values out of them.

```
%%[
var @SubscriberKey 

set @subscriberkey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows('EE_BookingExtensions_Cris',0,'[Tour Number] desc','SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey) 
SET @rowcount = RowCount(@rows) 

if @rowcount > 0 then 

    for @i = 1 to @rowcount do 

        set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
        set @tour = field(@row,"Tour Number")

        output(concat("<br>Tour Code from Sendable DE: ", @tour))

        SET @xml = Lookuprows('XML_CRISSS','TourCode', @tour)

        if rowcount(@xml) > 0 then 

            for @j = 1 to rowcount(@xml) do

                SET @xmlrows = row(@xml, @j)
                SET @xmlls = field(@xmlrows, "CODE__HTML")

                if indexOf(@xml,"<TourInfo>") > 0 then

                    set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/TourInfo/SellingCompanies/SellingCompany",0)
                    set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

                    for @k = 1 to @rowCount do

                        var @brochure
                        var @TourName

                        set @nodepath = concat("/TourInfo/SellingCompanies/SellingCompany[",@k,"]/")

                        if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"Brochure"))) > 0 then
                            set @brochure = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"Brochure"),0),1),'Value')
                        endif

                        if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"Name"))) > 0 then
                           set @TourName = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"Name"),0),1),'Value')
                        endif

                        output(concat("<br>Your brochure is: ", @brochure))
                        output(concat("<br>Your Tour Name is: ", @TourName))

                    next @k

                else 
                    output(concat("<br>no TourInfo found"))
                endif

            next @j 

        else
            output(concat("<br>no XML found"))
        endif

    next @i
else 
   output(concat("<br>no rows found"))
endif

]%%
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: XML path values in BuildRowSetFromXML() are case-sensitive